# How can I add a Dialog containing Form Data in container?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dojo

If I remove my dijit/Dialog i'm able to retrieve the current users and keys. But I would also like to give the user an option to add a new user. So, I implemented a form that would upload the names and a file (I'm using iframe this way because xhr and dojo's iframe just wouldn't do it! *sigh - Basically, it keeps me on this page(AJAX)). I think I'm almost there but need help here.

I'm new to fiddle, and for some reason my grids aren't showing: http://jsfiddle.net/ysabz/5WB4M/

```
  <body class="claro" style="background-color: #686868;">

  <h1 style= "width: 350px; color:#000000; margin: 20px auto;">USER/KEY 
  ADMINISTRATION</h1>

<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" id="tabContainer" style="width: 900px; 
height: 400px; margin: 20px auto;">

<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Users" data-dojo-
 id="usersPane"data-dojo-props="selected:true">  

 <div id="usersNode" style="width: 100%; height: 80%;"></div>      
  <button id="buttonThree" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button" 
 onClick="myFormDialog.show();">
   Add User!
  </button>
  </div>


<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Keys" data-dojo-id="keysPane">

<div id="keysNode" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

************Dialog call************************

```
 <div data-dojo-type="dijit/Dialog" data-dojo-id="myFormDialog" title="Form Dialog" 
            style="display: none">
  <iframe id="uploadTrg" name="uploadTrg" height="0" width="0"></iframe>
  <form id="myForm" encType="multipart/form-data" action="addUser" method="post" 
            target="uploadTrg">

  <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" size="30"/> </p>

 <p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" size="30" /> </p>

 <div class="dijitDialogPaneActionBar">
    <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="submit" onClick="return 
     myFormDialog.isValid();">
        OK
    </button>
    <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button"   
    onClick="myFormDialog.hide()">
        Cancel
    </button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: for adding gridx to jsFiddle, that entire js library need to be loaded into the fiddle. So, for simplicity i changed it to datagrid and made some changes. check it out here now - http://jsfiddle.net/vivek_nk/5WB4M/1/

Comment: Your fiddle looks good. However, my issue persists. I think it's the DOM b'se the Add User button seems to prevent the grids from populating. Notice how they are in the same ContentPane. Can you help me with this?  http://jsfiddle.net/ysabz/5WB4M/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**: Here's the correct method. Slight changes. I have three dialog boxes, here is one:

```
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/Dialog" data-dojo-id="myFormDialog" title="Add User" 
       style="display: none">

    <form data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" id="myForm" encType="multipart/form-data" 
    action="addUser" method="post" target="uploadTrg">
        <p>First Name:
            <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" type="text" name="fname" 
     size="30" />
        </p>
        <p>Last Name:
            <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" type="text" name="lname" 
      size="30" />
        </p>
        <p>Upload Cert: 
            <input type="file" name="fileName" /> 
        </p>

        <div class="dijitDialogPaneActionBar">

        <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="submit" onclick="return 
         myFunction();">Add</button>
        <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button" onclick="return 
         myFormDialog.hide();">Cancel</button>


        </div>     
        </form>

        </div>
```

************************* Calling Dialog********************

```
       <script>

       myFormDialog.show();
       </script>
```